# Keep original image ratio in {ggimage}

Tags: r, ggimage

I'm trying to use a non squared image in a `{ggimage}` layer but I can't seem to make the ratio fit the orignal image ratio. Documentation points to the `asp` argument but this doesn't seem to work.

Here's an obviously non square image : https://ps.w.org/insert-headers-and-footers/assets/banner-772x250.png

Here is the result from `{ggimage}`:

```r
library(ggimage)
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(
  x = 1,
  y = 1,
  image = "https://ps.w.org/insert-headers-and-footers/assets/banner-772x250.png"
)
```

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size = 1)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size = 1, asp = 0.1)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size = 1, asp = 0.5)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size = 1, asp = 0.9)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I make the image keep the original width/height ratio?